# How do I get SpecFlow.NUnit to suppress passing scenarios from console output?

Tags: nunit, specflow, nunit-console

When I run my SpecFlow suite with `dotnet test`, I don't want to see all the step output output from the passing scenarios.  I've got nearly 200 scenarios-- I only want to see what's broken!

This was working fine until I just upgraded all the test nugets in this 4-year-old project to the most recent (non-prerelease) versions.  Before, if everything passed, I'd see not much more than the summary line.  If something failed, I'd see only the steps for the broken tests.  I want this behavior back!

These are the current nugets I'm using:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.9.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="4.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" Version="3.17.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.9.74" />
        <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit" Version="3.9.74" />
        <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.9.74" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

**NUnit note:** If I downgrade all the SpecFlow projects to my previous version (3.3.57), I still see the problem.  **It appears that the NUnit upgrade was what actually introduced the output change.**

### Things I've tried:

**1. "verbosity" parameter of `dotnet test`**

`dotnet test --filter TestCategory!=wip koala.IntegrationTests/ -l "console;verbosity=quiet"`

The default is 'minimal', which prints the output I don't want.  This is the second-quietest setting.

The quietest setting is `quiet`, but that hides all failure output too, so that's no good.

**2. adding to the specflow.json file**

Per [this doc](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Installation/Configuration.html), I tried tweaking the specflow.json file in my SpecFlow project dir.  I added the setting "traceSuccessfulSteps", so now the file looks like:

```
{
  "bindingCulture": { "language" :"en-us" },
  "language": { "feature": "en-us" },
  "runtime": { "missingOrPendingStepsOutcome": "Error" },
  "trace": { "traceSuccessfulSteps": false },
  "plugins": []
}
```

No luck, I still see the passing output.  I don't see any other config settings that could apply.

**3. created a .runsettings file**

Per [this doc](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html), I created a .runsettings file next to the specflow csproj.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration/>
  <TestRunParameters/>
  <NUnit>
    <InternalTraceLevel>Error</InternalTraceLevel>
    <Verbosity>-1</Verbosity>
  </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```

I see no difference in output.

### How can I keep the passing-scenario steps out of my `dotnet test` console output?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include some example console output, and note the parts of the output you don't want shown? My answer is basically a hack, and doesn't really address the core part of our question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my hand at this anyways. I know in MS Test each test shows "Passed" or "Failed" on the command line. Assuming NUnit does something similar, pipe the test output to the [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) commandlet in PowerShell:

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory!=wip koala.IntegrationTests/ -l "console;verbosity=quiet" | Select-String 'Failed'
#                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Just replace `'Failed'` with a string that always occurs when a test fails, but not when a test passes. If you aren't familiar with PowerShell, the general pattern is:

```
dotnet test arguments | Select-String 'foo'
```

Where you replace `arguments` with whatever you normally pass to `dotnet test`. It should filter out all test output except for lines that match the pattern passed to `Select-String`.

---

I used to do this sort of thing all the time years ago developing a Ruby on Rails application. We had a Rake task that ran our tests similar to `dotnet test`. It showed a series of `******FFF*FFF*FFF***` characters where `*` meant a test passed, and `F` meant a test failed. Just a quick `rake test | grep 'F'` in Bash made for a lot less output to track visually.

Composable commands are a powerful tool I used all the time on Linux and MacOS. I frequently forget this on Windows, but PowerShell has some very powerful pipe commands as well.

Comment: When you are used to a Swiss Army knife always having what you need, sometimes it's hard to remember to pick up the hammer when you need to pound a nail.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt at a workaround, and I'm no stranger to bash redirects.  But I was hoping this question would find someone who understands the interplay between MSTest/NUnit/SpecFlow and could tell me why the output got worse after my upgrade.